# Meaning of "get a serious reaming"

Tags: slang, idiom-meaning

As a non-native reader, I stumbled upon the meaning of "get a serious reaming" and it seemed to be an idiomatic expression for being punished. At least the [first Google matches](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+a+serious+reaming%22) seem to suggest this.

Is this the whole truth, or does this idiom implicate something important besides it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translation into another language.

Comment: @Robusto: The fact that I wish to translate it, should be seen as decoration only. Maybe I should rephrase it a little...

Comment: Check Urban Dictionary before going headlong into a translation; you never know what words mean "other" stuff too.

Comment: Yes. At least don't lead with that. It gives the wrong impression.

Comment: @Frank I try to keep that in mind. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the meanings of the verb *[ream](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ream#ream-2)* is

> [North American INFORMAL] Rebuke someone fiercely:
>   *the agent was reaming him out for walking away from the deal*

The gerund form, *reaming*, is used as a noun to mean a serious rebuke.

Your phrase means *to receive a very serious rebuke*.

As to its source,  [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ream&searchmode=none) give a first use for this meaning as 1950, but does not indicate the derivation. It also notes as a meaning *anal sex*, dating back to 1942.

There may be a connection between these two uses. In US slang, it is not uncommon to use reference to unwelcome sexual contact to indicate a person was seriously harmed by someone who has power over them, as in

- *you got screwed*
- *he really fucked you over*
- *they stuck it to you* (similarly to *[schtupp](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/schtupp)*)

To the extent that *reaming* might be understood to refer to anal sex (in a pejorative way), it may have migrated to mean being abusively dominated and thence to humiliated through criticism.

Comment: ...than it means - *an expression of sharp disapproval or criticism* (Google translate) - a purely verbal action?

Comment: Yes. A reaming is a verbal attack, not a physical one. See additional info I just added about its possible source.

Comment: *To ream (out)* in the sense of a scathing reprimand probably derives from the original sense of *ream* meaning to widen or enlarge a hole, such as when one reams out the bore of a gun.  It’s like saying you’re going to rip somebody a new one.

Comment: @tchrist I think that *ripping somebody a new one* refers to a new anus. I also think that the sexual reference may well have come from the concept of mechanical reaming of a hole.

Comment: Certainly — and on both counts.

Comment: As tchrist mentioned: to "ream" something often involves scraping out material using a sharp object. Metaphorically, if someone punishes you, you might feel as if you had been yourself attacked with said object.

Answer (score 1):

The reference is to "ass reaming", a colloquialism for the situation where a superior (officer or manager) "reads the riot act" (look it up -- there are several good references) to an underling.

Of course, "ass reaming" refers to sodomizing someone, in the literal sense.

Answer (score -1):

The idiom is derived from military jargon meaning to ream out the bore of a gun or artillery piece.  The act of reaming is a harsh cleaning out of the inside of the gun, with a heavy swab, to remove any residues from previous firings.  A "serious reaming" can affect the lands and grooves of the barrel, so a serious reaming is not something you do often, just in cases of absolute necessity.

Comment: Do you have any reference to support your answer? Please include it if you have.